# Get common elements with index from two list C#

Tags: c#, list, intersect

I have Two lists of type `list<int>` and i know we can find the common elements between two lists. But **is there any way to get common elements and corresponding indexes of common elements in Intersected list** or i need to go across each elements find the indexes.

Comment: Can you show your code and also show an example?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You certainly *can* do this with LINQ, although I suspect it's about as much code with as without.

Comment: There are now two answers, one of which only matches when the values are the same *and* the indexes are the same, and one of which matches just on values (giving two indexes for each match). Which did you want?

Answer (score 4):

LINQ has operations to project a sequence using indexes, but this isn't built into the query expression syntax, so you have to use "regular" extension method calls to start with. After that it's fairly easy, although probably just as simple not using LINQ, to be honest:

```
var pairs1 = list1.Select((value, index) => new { value, index });
var pairs2 = list2.Select((value, index) => new { value, index });
var matches = from pair1 in pairs1
              join pair2 in pairs2 on pair1.value equals pair2.value
              select new
              {
                  Value = pair1.value,
                  Index1 = pair1.index,
                  Index2 = pair2.index
              };
```

(You could use `from pair2 in pairs2 where pair1.value == pair2.value` if you'd prefer...)

Or non-LINQ (using `Tuple<,,>` for simplicity; other options are feasible):

```
var results = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
for (int index1 = 0; index1 < list1.Count; index1++)
{
    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < list2.Count; index2++)
    {
        if (list1[index1] == list2[index2])
        {
            results.Add(Tuple.Of(list1[index1], index1, index2);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that unlike a regular intersection operation, both of these can give you multiple results for the same value - because there can be multiple index pairs. For example, with lists of `{ 1, 2 }` and `{2, 2, 0}`, you'd have tuples of (value=2,index1=1,index2=0), (value=2,index1=1,index2=1).

Comment: I just used this answer to create a new object from a json string that i consumed from a node rest api. This is awesome. Thanks again for saving the day @Jon Skeet !

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
List<int> lstA = new List<int>() { 10, 2, 7, 9, 13, 21, 17 };
List<int> lstB = new List<int>() { 2, 10, 7, 21, 13, 9, 17 };

var lstA_Temp = lstA.Select((value, index) => new { index, value }).ToList();
var lstB_Temp = lstB.Select((value, index) => new { index, value }).ToList();


List<int> result = (from A in lstA_Temp from B in lstB_Temp
                    where A.index == B.index where A.value == B.value
                    select A.value).ToList();
```

you can also do this thing without linq see below logic

```
List<int> lstA = new List<int>() { 10, 2, 7, 9, 13, 21, 17 };
List<int> lstB = new List<int>() { 2, 10, 7, 21, 13, 9, 17 };

List<int> lstResult = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < lstA.Count; i++)
{
    if (lstA[i] == lstB[i])
        lstResult.Add(lstA[i]);
}
```

Comment: Note that if you're matching on index as well, it would be simpler to use `Zip` IMO.